# How do I make the returned integer value in this program print a message, depending on the value?

Tags: java

I have semi-successfully coded this program. As it stands, it prints an integer value as a result of what you type in. The only results can be 0, 1, or 2. I am wondering how to make java display a message for each one of those 3 integer values. For instance, a returned result of 0 might make it print "You received no ticket", while a result of 2 would say "You're going to jail, buddy!" Any tips on how I could do this?

I know the answer is probably very simple; bear with me, as I am just starting out :)

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpeedingBool {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.println("Your ticket is " + caughtSpeeding(input));
      
   }
   
   public static int caughtSpeeding(Scanner input) {
      System.out.println("How fast were you going?");
      int speed = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("True or false: today is your birthday");
      boolean isBirthday = input.nextBoolean();
      int ticket;
      if (isBirthday) {
         if (speed <= 65)
            ticket = 0;
         else if (speed > 65 && speed <= 85)
            ticket = 1;
         else ticket = 2;
      }
      else {
         if (speed <= 60)
            ticket = 0;
         else if (speed > 60 && speed <= 80)
            ticket = 1;
         else ticket = 2;
      }
      return ticket;
   }

}
```

Comment: Just use `if (result == 0) {System.out.println("Blah")}`  and add `else if` for each result similar to how you made the `caughtSpeeding` code?  You can also use a `switch` statement, but I would start with `if-else` since you are already familiar with those.

Comment: Just go with if-else on the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go with simple if-else on returned value. I am giving you an example with some minor logical improvements.

```
else if (speed > 65 && speed <= 85)
                ticket = 1;
```

this line will only reach is the speed is already greater than 65. So you can do this:

```
else if (speed <= 85)
                ticket = 1;
```

Similar for this:

```
else if (speed > 60 && speed <= 80)
                ticket = 1;
```

Make it like this:

```
else if (speed <= 80)
                ticket = 1;
```

And finally the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpeedingBool {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = caughtSpeeding(input);

        String ticket;

        if (i == 0)
            ticket = "You received no ticket";
        else if (i == 1)
            ticket = "Return value 1 ticket";
        else
            ticket = "You're going to jail, buddy!";

        System.out.println("Your ticket is " + ticket);

    }

    public static int caughtSpeeding( Scanner input ) {
        System.out.println("How fast were you going?");
        int speed = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("True or false: today is your birthday");
        boolean isBirthday = input.nextBoolean();
        int ticket;
        if (isBirthday) {
            if (speed <= 65)
                ticket = 0;
            else if (speed <= 85)
                ticket = 1;
            else ticket = 2;
        } else {
            if (speed <= 60)
                ticket = 0;
            else if (speed <= 80)
                ticket = 1;
            else ticket = 2;
        }
        return ticket;
    }
}
```